# How to handle testcase failed scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

In TestNG , 
I wrote one  method to register in any application up to 100 users for example, then i write the code take inputs(User id & password) from excel file and register those users,
when ever i run its failed in some 45 or 46th user registration , if i run it again its fails because of up to 45 users already registered, how can i over come this problem.

```
package com.stm.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class RegistrationTest
{

    @Test //This is TestNG annotation
    public void testRegister()
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(“http://newtours.demoaut.com/”);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(“REGISTER”)).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name(“firstName”)).sendKeys(“User1”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“lastName”)).sendKeys(“Surname1”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“phone”)).sendKeys(“123456789”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“userName”)).sendKeys(“user1@test.com”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“address1”)).sendKeys(“Test Address”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“city”)).sendKeys(“Test City”);
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name(“country”)));
        select.selectByVisibleText(“ANGOLA”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“email”)).sendKeys(“user1@test.com”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“password”)).sendKeys(“user1”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“confirmPassword”)).sendKeys(“user1”);
        driver.findElement(By.name(“register”)).click();
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I write this for one user, but I want to register more users from excel file.

Comment: Consider formatting your code.

Comment: Consider using [DataProvider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Comment: While you referred input data from excel, your code is irrelevant, since you have hard-coded the data. Solution to your problem lies in the field of how you supply test data and how you let TestNG engine to invoke test methods. See answer below for guidance.

Comment: also in general, tests should be independent and dont change any production value. why do you need to test that 46 registerings are possible ? This fails of course when rerunning the test. The test should clean up in any case, e.g. unregister all registered user.